# Update user settings table - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to update a table that holds a user's settings. I have a `hasOne` usersetting relation setup in the user model. The usersetting table doesn't have a id column. But Im getting this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: update `usersettings` set `user_name` = u9ddf,
>   `usersettings`.`updated_at` = 2019-04-30 02:13:37 where `id` is null).

```
public function profileupdate(Request $request)
{
    if($user = Auth::user())
    {
        $usersetting = $user->usersetting;
        $usersetting->update([
            'user_name' => $request->input('profile_name')
        ]);


        return redirect('profilesettings');
    }


}
```

I guess Im not querying correctly with eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in model usersetting:

```
protected $primaryKey  = 'user_id';
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Had to set user_id as a primary key in usersetting model.

```
public $primaryKey  = 'user_id';
```

Comment: It should be protected